# split text by 1st ";" and then again by 2nd ";"

Tags: javascript, regex, split

i need to split this text using reg exp. so far i managed to split text and i did manage to split by ";" using

var array3 = fText.match(/(\d;)/g);

and result is [ 1;1;2;1;3;2;4;2;5;3;6;3;]

but what i actually need is to split text by only 1st ";" so i get one array which will loook [1,2,3,4,5,6...] and then to split by 2nd ";" so i get array of [1,1,2,2,3,3....]

```
1;1; Podkategorija1
2;1; Podkategorija2
3;2; Podkategorija3
4;2; Podkategorija4
5;3; Podkategorija5
6;3; Podkategorija6
```

Comment: i used var array = fText.replace(/(\d;)/g,"").split("\n");  to split text Podkategorija1, Podkategorija2... 
so now i need to split by ";" so i get these numbers which ill use as ids

Comment: Hmm... Maybe you've misunderstood [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method. There's no `;`s in your text, so it can't be splitted by `;` either.

Comment: Man i have txt file which looks exactly like  i wrote above 
    1;1; podkategorija1
    2;2; podkategorija2

I need these numbers before the text do u understand  me?

Comment: Hmm... Please take a look at your question and comment. In the comment you say the text is `Podkategorija1, Podkategorija2...`, in the question there's only `this text`... The text is `1;1;Podkategorija1;2;2;Podkategorija2, ...`?

Comment: well i count numbers as text as well isnt it and anyway falsetru asnwered me corectly thxs anyway on ur time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
var s = 
    '1;1; Podkategorija1\n' +
    '2;1; Podkategorija2\n' +
    '3;2; Podkategorija3\n' +
    '4;2; Podkategorija4\n' +
    '5;3; Podkategorija5\n' +
    '6;3; Podkategorija6\n';
console.log(s.match(/^[^;]*(?=;)/mg));
console.log(s.match(/^([^;]*;){2}/mg).map(function(s) { return s.split(';')[1]; }));
```

prints

```
[ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' ]
[ '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3' ]
```

Comment: @user2599279 Please accept the answer if it works for you, this way you will make people think that you still haven't found an accepted solution.

Comment: @falsetru sry im new to this site i did not know how it works i did it now

Answer (score 0):

```
var nums = input.split(/\n/).map(function (line) { 
    return line.split(/;/).slice(0,2);
});
```

gives

```
[
  ["1","1"],
  ["2","1"],
  ["3","2"],
  ["4","2"],
  ["5","3"],
  ["6","3"]
]
```

for the multi-line string

```
1;1; Podkategorija1
2;1; Podkategorija2
3;2; Podkategorija3
4;2; Podkategorija4
5;3; Podkategorija5
6;3; Podkategorija6
```